# Sign up banner can't be closed

Tags: bug, status-planned

[image: Web banner]

I try to close the web banner and it's not work on Chrome and Safari.

Another question is why we needs two "Sign up" button?

- MacOS: 10.13.4
- Chrome: v67.0.3396.87
- Safari: v11.1

Comment: Reproduced (Mac/Chrome).  What's shown in the screenshot here is actually the *second* version of that banner; when you first visit you get a larger one (with graphics) that summarizes how the site works.  When you click the 'x' on that one you get this one.  I suspect we're only supposed to see one of them.

Comment: hmm. It uses the cookie for dismiss banner. But it works after refresh the page.

Comment: Ah, I didn't refresh -- just popped into an incognito window, dismissed the larger banner, saw the smaller banner, tried to dismiss *that*, and it didn't go.